# Generate a unique uuid for each row in a table with Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a UUID constraint set up as my Id field in one of my tables, however despite this (I think due to the fact that uuid_generate_v4 only creates on UUID per transaction?) when I imported a load of CSV data into my table, each row in the table was given the same UUID.

I want to be able to change this and give each row a unique UUID, however running

`update monitors_nontest set id = uuid_generate_v1()`

Again only produces one UUID for each row.

How can I change this command so that each row gets a different UUID?

Comment: Not sure why `uuid_generate_v1()` doesn't, but `uuid_generate_v4()` works as you expect it.

Comment: Post the answers to the following questions into your original question. What version of Postgres? What is schema definition for the table you are importing into? This: `update monitors_nontest set id = uuid_generate_v1()` is probably not working as expected as per [Docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/uuid-ossp.html) 'This involves the MAC address of the computer and a time stamp'. I'm guessing it is using something like `now()` which stays constant for the entire transaction.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Read the source, your guess is wrong. It calls external library functions. It would be interesting to know the output of `pg_config --configure` so that we know which `--with-uuid` option was chosen.

Comment: For the record: I cannot reproduce that with the PGDG RPMs on Fedora Linux. They are configured with `--with-uuid=e2fs`.

Answer (score 0):

Just a possibility. How did you actually generate the uuid? The function uuid_generate_v1() actually generates a different value each time it is called. But that is the key **each time it is called**. It seems if called within a sub select the Postgres optimizer may feel it can bypass the call and use cached result. Try the following.

```
create table uuid_gen( id1a uuid
                     , id1b uuid
                     , num1 integer
                     );
                 
insert into uuid_gen(num1) 
  select generate_series(1,50);

update uuid_gen set id1a = uuid_generate_v1();
update uuid_gen set id1b = (select uuid_generate_v1());

select count(distinct id1a), count(distinct id1b) from uuid_gen;
```

Unfortunately, I could not find a fiddle processor that had the function uuid_generate_v1() available, nor uuid_generate_v4() which worked exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had not exactly the same problem, but something similar.
I was working with **pre-Postgres13** version (so I did not have any function ready).

I had a table where I needed to insert new rows into the table while generating a new UUID(v4) for each new row.

I was looking everywhere but couldn't find anything w/o creating a function or installing extensions.

So I made it this way:

```sql
INSERT INTO monitors_nontest (id, col1, col2, col3)
SELECT uuid_in(md5(random()::text || random()::text)::cstring), mn.col1, mn.col2, mn.col3 
FROM monitors_nontest mn
WHERE mn.col1 = 'some-text'
```

This could be adjusted for the `UPDATE` query. I hope it will help somebody else.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
UPDATE monitors_nontest
SET id = md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid;
```

This command fills the "id" UUID column of your table. The `random()` function generates a random decimal number, and the `clock_timestamp()` function returns the current timestamp. These two values are concatenated and hashed using the MD5 algorithm, and finally converted to the UUID data type using `::uuid`.